Cannot Parse JSON in Azure Function
I work for a MSP and am currently working on creating an automation process for offboarding employees for all of our clients. Currently, I am using Pipedream to receive HTTP requests and then execute code on what is received before sending it to Azure Functions. I have to use PowerShell to convert mailboxes to shared mailboxes as this is not supported by the Graph API and my reason for needing Azure Functions. The issue I am running into is that the Azure Function cannot parse the JSON that I am sending it from Pipedream. Therefore, no mailbox is ever converted to shared. I have created multiple different Python scripts and verified that it is sending what I want. The function key is included in the URL so that should not be causing any issues. I have also tested the mailbox conversion portion of the Azure Function and know that it works. I just need it to be able to actually use the JSON I am sending it. Any advice on what I may need to add to the Azure Function in dependencies or in the function itself would be greatly appreciated. I have pasted the code snippets below. The Azure Function URL and the other things have been replaced by *** for obvious security reasons. The JSON body being sent is:
{
"Name": "***"
}
Here is the Python code for sending a HTTP request to the Azure Function:
import requests
import json

def handler(pd: "pipedream"):
    url = "***"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    
    username_value = pd.steps["create_username"]["$return_value"]["username"]
    payload = {
      "Name": username_value
    }
    
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    
    print("Payload being sent:", json.dumps(payload))
    print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response Body:", response.text)

Here is the Azure Function:
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Add initial logging
Write-Host "Function triggered"

# Variables for OAuth 2.0 authentication
$tenantId = "***"
$clientId = "***"
$clientSecret = "***"
$tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Log the raw request body
Write-Host "Raw Request Body: $($Request.Body)"

# Try to parse the JSON request body
try {
    $requestBody = $Request.Body | ConvertFrom-Json
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to parse JSON: $_"
    return
}

# Extract the "Name" value from the JSON request
$name = $requestBody.Name

# Log the extracted name value
Write-Host "Extracted Name: $name"

# Ensure that $name has a value
if (-not [System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($name)) {
    Write-Host "Name parameter received: $name"

    try {
        Write-Host "Obtaining access token"
        $body = @{
            grant_type    = "client_credentials"
            scope         = "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
            client_id     = $clientId
            client_secret = $clientSecret
        }
        $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenEndpoint -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
        $accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

        Write-Host "Access token obtained successfully."

        # Connect to Exchange Online using the obtained access token
        Write-Host "Connecting to Exchange Online"
        Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId $clientId -AccessToken $accessToken -Organization $tenantId -ShowBanner:$false

        # Convert the mailbox to shared
        Write-Host "Converting mailbox to shared: $name"
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $name -Type Shared -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Mailbox converted to shared successfully."
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error during script execution: $_"
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "Name parameter is missing or empty in the JSON request."
}

Write-Host "Script execution completed."

Here is the requirements file for the Azure Function:
# This file enables modules to be automatically managed by the Functions service.
# See https://aka.ms/functionsmanageddependency for additional information.
#
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 
    # To use the Az module in your function app, please uncomment the line below.
    # 'Az' = '12.*'
    'ExchangeOnlineManagement' = '3.*'
    'PowerShellGet' = '2.*'
    'PackageManagement' = '1.*'
}

Thank you for taking the time to read this and any help is greatly appreciated.
Here are the invocation details for the function:
8/8/2024, 12:24:36 PM
Information
Executing 'Functions.Convert_to_Shared_Mailbox' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=97bb041f-a775-4091-ad9e-aeb8314dc193)
8/8/2024, 12:24:37 PM
Information
INFORMATION: Function triggered
8/8/2024, 12:24:37 PM
Information
INFORMATION: Raw Request Body: System.Management.Automation.OrderedHashtable
8/8/2024, 12:24:37 PM
Information
INFORMATION: Failed to parse JSON: Conversion from JSON failed with error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.
8/8/2024, 12:24:37 PM
Information
Executed 'Functions.Convert_to_Shared_Mailbox' (Succeeded, Id=97bb041f-a775-4091-ad9e-aeb8314dc193, Duration=1104ms)

You are getting error because you are already sending data/payload in JSON format, and you are converting it from JSON to string using ConverFrom-JSON, and accessing the Name using JSON method.
you need to remove ConvertFrom-JSON and use ConvertTo-JSON  if you payload is in different format.
As you are already sending payload in JSON2, no need to use ConvertFrom-JSON and ConvertTo-JSON.
Below given code worked for me:
I am using your  python code and created a sample HttpTrigger and using the payload to pass the value.
data.py:
import requests
import json

url = "http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

username_value = "Vivek"
payload = {
    "Name": username_value
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

print("Payload being sent:", json.dumps(payload))
print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
print("Response Body:", response.text)

HttpTrigger1/run.ps1:
using namespace System.Net


param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})

OUTPUT:
Payload being sent: {"Name": "Vivek"}
Status Code: 200
Response Body: Hello, Vivek. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.



